# Why does 'a:hover' doesnt effect 'img'?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

So, I want to increase border size and decrease padding in an img tag when a sibling a tag is hovered. But somehow it doesnt work. Here is my html and css code, i tried using "+" and "~" on css but still doesnt work.

This is my code:

```css
        #Body #Banner {
            width: 500px;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 3px solid #eee;
        }
        #Button:hover + #Banner {
            padding: 12px;
            border: 6px;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="Body">
        <img src="https://u.ph.edim.co/6c19/80017655_7_140.png" id="Banner"><br>    
        <a href="#.html" id="Button">Press to continue</a><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: CSS selectors can't go backwards/up the DOM.

Comment: What can I do to fix it then?

Comment: switch the order of `#Button` and `#Banner` in the HTML

Comment: Thanks man, best fix so far.

Comment: Have you considered using JavaScript? Would you?

Comment: I am trying to refrain from using JS for designing tho. Still figuring out a css fix tho. :)